# how can i use filter to check if specific user's social media link is correct?

Tags: python, django

```py
def userProfile(request, pk):

    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    rooms = user.room_set.all()
    room_messages = user.message_set.all()
    topics = Topic.objects.all()

    link_fb = User.objects.filter(Q(link_fb__icontains='facebook'))
    link_ig = User.objects.filter(Q(link_ig__icontains='instagram'))
    link_lin = User.objects.filter(Q(link_lin__icontains='linkedin'))

    context = {'user': user, 'rooms': rooms, 'room_messages': room_messages,
               'topics': topics, 'link_fb': link_fb, 'link_ig': link_ig,
               'link_lin': link_lin}
    return render(request, 'base/profile.html', context)
```

I've got something like this. I want to check if url is correct.
Problem is i can not get specific user and then use filter. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Is the searched for user, nut in your `user` variable? You can just check the attributes of that model no?

Comment: Yes it is, but problem is i don't know how to get ,,link_fb" attribute to check if the value of that string is correct.

Comment: How does your user model look like?

Comment: `class User(AbstractUser):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, default="avatar.svg")

   link_fb = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    link_ig = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    link_lin = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)`

Comment: Its a lot cleaner to just edit it into your question, but looking at it you van just check `if "facebook" in user.link_fb` or something similar

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious things take the most time. Thank you for your help <3